# Android- joan zapata pdf view library issue

Tags: android, pdf

I used joan zapata pdf view library to read pdf files in my app. which I downloaded from  GitHub

The issue is when i open pdf files some of the files are not shown properly a [black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fseQz.png) image is shown upon title page of pdf file. But when i open the same file in pdf reader its shows proper [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhD2m.png) .
can anyone pin point the problem?

Comment: i downloaded it from here https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/tree/master/android-pdfview-sample

Comment: Can you post your code where you modify/set your pdfView ?

Comment: i didnt find solution then instead joan zapata i used this library  https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/1124      its performance is much better that joan zapata

Comment: Not sure of speed, but I feel joan zapata's library has superior design, as it enables usage of pdfView as a component just like imageView, videoView and webView. Except for those minor bugs, I feel this lib is awesome.